# Populate SAS variable based on content of another variable

Tags: sas

I have a variable, `textvar`, that looks like this:

```
type=1&name=bob
type=2&name=sue
```

I want to create a new table that looks like this:

```
type  name
1     bob
2     sue
```

My approach is to use `scan` to split the variables on `&` so for the first observation I have

```
var1      var2
type=1    name=bob
```

So now I can use scan again to split on `=`:

```
vname = scan(var1, 1, '=');
value = scan(var1, 2, '=');
```

But how can I now assign `value` to the variable named `vname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PROC TRANPSOSE is the quickest way.  You need an ID variable (dummy or real).

```
data test;
informat testvar $50.;
input testvar $;
datalines;
type=1&name=bob
type=2&name=sue
;;;;
run;

data test_vert;
set test;
id+1;
length scanner $20 vname vvalue $20;
scanner=scan(testvar,1,"&");
do _t=2 by 1 until (scanner=' ');   
    vname=scan(scanner,1,"=");
    vvalue=scan(scanner,2,"=");
    output;
    scanner=scan(testvar,_t,"&");
end;
run;

proc transpose data=test_vert out=test_T;
by id;
id vname;
var vvalue;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? [Dynamic variable names in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798393/dynamic-variable-names-in-sas)

I think I have some code to address this, but left it at my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you haven't included your real data, but can't you just hard code some of the values if the format of the raw data is the same in each row?  My code converts the "=" and "&" to "," to make the scan function easier to use.

```
data want (keep=type name);
set test;
_newvar=translate(testvar,",,","&=");
    type=input(scan(_newvar,2),best12.);
    length name $20;
    name=scan(_newvar,4);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my real data the order of the variables can change so I can't hard-code it.