# dynamic variable name in sas

Tags: arrays, sas

with similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798393/dynamic-variable-names-in-sas), My situation is a bit difference that Variable name are Var12, Var 24, Var36 instead of Var1 Var2 and Var3.

It gives Array Subscript out of range error.

```
data have;
input Index Var12 Var2 Var3;
cards;
12      78.3   54.7  79.8
36      67.2   56.2  12.3
24      65.3   45.2  98.1
12      56.2   49.7  11.3
12      67.2   98.2  98.6
;
run;

data want;
set have;
array vars(*) var: ;
var_index=vars(Index);
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into `vvaluex` function instead. It allows you to specify a string defining the variable, versus `vvalue` which takes a variable name (not a string).

```
Var_index=vvaluex('var'||put(index, 2. -l));
```

Comment: This seems easiest to me.  I added a bit of explanation so the answer was more complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your `input` statement...

Assuming it should be

```
input Index Var12 Var24 Var36 ;
```

Then this code works if the input `var` fields have any numeric suffix and in any order :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array vars{*} var: ;
  var_index = . ;
  do i = 1 to dim(vars) ;
    /* Get variable name of vars{i}, keep only digits, compare to var_index */
    /* If they match, store the value from vars{i} */
    if input(compress(vname(vars{i}),,'kd'),8.) = index then var_index = vars{i} ;
  end ;

  drop i ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 3 variables with names starting with var, the array of 3 numeric variables will be created and therefore index value should be between 1 to 3.

Any value above 3 will give out of range error. You can use dim function to find out number of elements in the array declared.

code statement:

```
num_val = dim(vars);
```

Comment: This would be a good comment, because it points out an error in the code, but it doesn't actually answer the question - the question is how to create `var_index`, which this doesn't do.